# php regex get name and author of a book

Tags: php, regex

I have some book names that are like this

```
lastname, firstname - bookname.extension
firstname lastname - bookname.extension
```

I wanted to use a php regex to change this formats into

bookname - firstname lastname.extension

I hope there is an easy way to make a regex to extract an array having the firstname, lastname, author and extension.

Comment: Yup, there is: http://php.net/pcre   good luck!

Comment: Cite: "I wanted to use a php regex to change this formats"... Great! So where is your code so far? How should we help with it, if you do not show it?

Comment: Try out regex's here, https://regex101.com/r/zM3mU8/1 when you have something you should add that to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say my solution

```
<?php 
$book = "Alfred, Zusak - Time of the death.pdf";

$book = preg_replace("#^([a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]+)\,([a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)$#isU", "$3 - $2 $1.$4", $book);
echo $book;
?>
```

Comment: The `-` in the character class should be escaped or moved. You also should explain your answer... or make character class into `[\w. -]`.

Comment: wow this is an amazing response, could you explain a little how this works please ?